# How to properly bind a Django form?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a form that picks a Sale id and submits it to the server.
When i submit it to the server a bind it using `form = DeleteSalesForm(request.POST)`
and check it `form.is_bound` returns False.
This is my views.py

```py
def delete_sales(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/login')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = DeleteSalesForm()
        print("GET")
        return render(request, 'inventorymanagment/delete_sales.html', {'form': form})
    form = DeleteSalesForm(request.POST)
    print("checking if form is valid", request.POST, form.is_bound, form)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.delete_sale()
        # redirect
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print("sale not deleted")
        # why is the form invalid?
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'inventorymanagment/delete_sales.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is forms.py

```py
class DeleteSalesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sales
        fields = ['id']
        labels = {
            'id': 'Sale',
        }

    def clean(self):
        self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
        id = int(self.cleaned_data.get('id')[0])
        print('id', id)
        if id <= 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('ID cannot be negative')
        print('id > 0', id)
        # check if id in database
        if id not in Sales.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True):
            raise forms.ValidationError('ID not in database')
        print("id in database", id)
        return id

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.fields['id'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            label="Sale", choices=[(i.id, i) for i in Sales.objects.all()], required=True)

    def delete_sale(self):
        id = self.cleaned_data.get('id')
        print('id', id)
        sale = Sales.objects.get(id=id)
        print('sale', sale)
        item = sale.item
        print('item', item)
        item.remaining += sale.quantity
        item.sold -= sale.quantity
        item.save()
        sale.delete()
        return True

    def validate_unique(self) -> None:
        print("validate_unique")
        return super().validate_unique()

    def validate_constraints(self) -> None:
        print("validate_constraints")
        return super().validate_constraints()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
[31/Aug/2022 15:38:36] "POST /delete_sales HTTP/1.1" 200 932
checking if form is valid <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['q3aga7bySuscQ6bb9zrh3pFUlfoIoRoGQnHvQQ8LlbiEfUl1XDSGp2fk3nCj5KJk'], 'id': ['16']}> False <tr>
    <th><label for="id_id">Sale:</label></th>
    <td>

      <select name="id" id="id_id">
  <option value="16">id: 16, iphone 6 quantity: 50 price: 30.00 day: 2022-08-31</option>

  <option value="17">id: 17, Iphone 8 quantity: 70 price: 80.00 day: 2022-08-31</option>

</select>




    </td>
  </tr>
sale not deleted
```

why isn't the form validating?

Comment: try replacing `print(form.errors)` with `print(form.errors.as_data())` ..it'll give you a dictionary like: `{'id':'{errormsg}'}` .. but could you also post the form.py?

Comment: Hi i edited the question to include forms.py and i tried `form.errors.as_data())` but it returns an empty dictionary `{}`

Comment: `is_bound` is false if no data has been provided to the form. This indicates that something is wrong with your html form markup or how the post request is created. You have not provided the markup of the form. Make sure that the form uses `method="POST"` and the form and model field names match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are currently overwriting the `__init__` method of the form incorrectly.

Try passing in the `*args` and `**kwargs` as arguments to constructor method of the parent class.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['id'] = forms.ChoiceField(
    label="Sale", choices=[(i.id, i) for i in Sales.objects.all()], required=True)
```